# Css gets scattered while loading a page in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular8

I am building an angular project where I am using pre designed html templates .I am using lazy loading while loading my pages ,I don't exactly know how to describe the issue all I can say that when I load the page ,the css gets scattered as shown in the gif  I am attaching.
[image]

I have created common navbar and footer components and all the css links are there .Following is the code of my homepagecomponent.html

```
<app-basehome></app-basehome>
<app-navbarhome></app-navbarhome>
<body>
// Rest Html
</body>

<app-footerhome></app-footerhome>
```

Can anyone tell me why is this issue and how to solve it ?? .I am guessing it might be because of lazy loading .

My app.routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';



const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    loadChildren:'./website/website.module#WebsiteModule'
  },

  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am just putting css files in the src/assets folder and providing the links like

```
 <!-- Owl Carousel ->
        <link href="/assets/home/common/owl-carousel/css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Fancybox -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/home/common/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css" type="text/css" />   
        <!-- Theme Style -->
        <link href="/assets/home/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Did you add css to current component's css or global styles file?

Comment: for global css you have to put class in `style.css` and for each component you have to set css-class in respective component.css

Comment: Umm actually I am just putting css files in the assets folder available and providing the links.

Comment: Then you have to import the css file from global styles.css or (scss- if you use scss) file

Comment: Please see the update in my question. @DilshanJayasanka

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: No errors ,all is loading fine but with the effect in the pic

Comment: Did you check your network tab ? Are css files getting load or not ?

Comment: yes they are loading

Comment: can you set up a stack blitz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of just including the files in component html files just import them in style.css (global style.css) like

```
@import "/assets/home/common/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css";
```

Look at the following [reference](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#css-imports)

Comment: that''s actually kinda worked ,but waiting for some more declarative answers.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, It is normal behavior of Angular applications, the css is applied after the application has been fully loaded.

The only workaround you can adopt is to create a `.css` file where you insert all the styles that must be applied with high priority and include it in the `index.html` in the head, in doing so you will have a significant improvement but I don't know if you will solve altogether.

Also, even if unsightly, you can include your style in the head without importing a link, but directly on the page between the `<style>` tags, improving performance by another 15% - 20%.

---

If anyone knows a better method, I would be very happy that you suggested it.

Comment: Yes .It seems so. But I have predefined styles which i can't segregate.though importing css as per @shubh worked

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution which I tested from this site.

[Alex Jover Preload](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/html-preload-prefetch)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/html-preload-prefetch

Use the following in the head tag in the index.html

```
<link
  rel="preload"
  as="style"
  onload="this.rel = 'stylesheet'"
  href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css'>
```

In my tests this caused the page to lock, showing nothing (not even my spinner) until the css was loaded in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

transform link css to angular.json file

[image: see example]